# How to Join 3 Table in LINQ using Method Syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I have joined two tables in method syntax using Except method. and written another query to join third table because I dont have more than 1 common columns to select. SO, I want to combine these two queries into one using Method syntax.

Note that, I have to use method sytanx in linq and Except() is must..

```
var EResult = dbContext.Table1.Where(x => x.ID >= 5
                               && x.TID == 1
                               && x.SID == rModel.SID)                           
                               .Select(s => s.ID)
                               .Except(dbContext.Table2.Select(s => s.ID))
                               .ToList();

                            List<rModel> Result = (from t1 in dbContext.Table1
                                      join t3 in dbContext.Table3 on t1.BID equals t3.BID
                                      where EResult.Contains(t1.ID)
                                      select new RTableModel
                                      {
                                          ID = t1.ID,
                                          SCode = t1.SCode,
                                          time = t1.time.ToString(),
                                     .
                                   .......
                                }
```

Here the problem is, I am accessing table 1 twice so I want to combine it into single query using method syntax and here Except() is must..

How to Combine these two queries into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command:

```
List<rModel> Result = (from t1 in dbContext.Table1
                   join t3 in dbContext.Table3 on t1.BID equals t3.BID
                   where (t1.ID >= 5 && t1.TID == 1 && t1.SID == rModel.SID 
                          && !dbContext.Table2.Select(s => s.ID).Contains(t1.ID))                           
                   select new RTableModel
                   {
                       ID = t1.ID,
                       SCode = t1.SCode,
                       time = t1.time.ToString()
                   }
```

or simply put table2 ids into a variable:

```
var ids = dbContext.Table2.Select(s => s.ID).ToList();
```

and use:

```
List<rModel> Result = (from t1 in dbContext.Table1
                   join t3 in dbContext.Table3 on t1.BID equals t3.BID
                   where (t1.ID >= 5 && t1.TID == 1 && t1.SID == rModel.SID 
                          && !ids.Contains(t1.ID))                           
                   select new RTableModel
                   {
                       ID = t1.ID,
                       SCode = t1.SCode,
                       time = t1.time.ToString()
                   }
```

Using `Except` doesn't helps you as it's argument should be the same type of your collection but here is an example of using `Except`:

```
List<rModel> Result = (from t1 in dbContext.Table1
                   join t3 in dbContext.Table3 on t1.BID equals t3.BID
                   where (t1.ID >= 5 && t1.TID == 1 && t1.SID == rModel.SID)                         
                   select new RTableModel
                   {
                       ID = t1.ID,
                       SCode = t1.SCode,
                       time = t1.time.ToString()
                   }
 Result = Result.Except(Result.Where(P => ids.Contains(P.ID)));
```

This will give accurate result

Comment: I want to do it using except() is it possible?

Comment: I will edit the answer.

Comment: remove ! from ids.Contains because its giving wrong answer